# The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I upgrade my Flutter and I find some errors

the versions now are as below:

***Flutter 3.10.6
Dart 3.0.6
DevTools 2.23.1***

and when I run `flutter pub get` I see the message below:

The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.6.

Because flutter_app depends on flutter_staggered_grid_view >=0.1.1 <0.4.0-nullsafety.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=1.19.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic data
along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash reports.
This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework, and related tools.

Telemetry is not sent on the very first run.
To disable reporting of telemetry, run this terminal command:

flutter --disable-telemetry.
If you opt out of telemetry, an opt-out event will be sent,
and then no further information will be sent.
This data is collected in accordance with the
Google Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy).

Please note that analytics reporting was already disabled, and will continue to be disabled.

Process finished with exit code 1

**pubspic.yml**

```
name: Flutter App
description: A new Flutter project.
    version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  provider: ^6.0.3
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.4
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  firebase_core: ^1.20.1
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.4
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.3
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.4.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.1
  flutter_iconly: ^1.0.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.6.1
  loader_overlay: ^2.0.7
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  get:
  lottie:
  json_annotation:
  google_fonts: ^2.3.1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.2
  edge_alerts: ^0.0.1
  mongo_dart: ^0.7.4+1
  easy_localization: ^3.0.2-dev
  geoflutterfire: ^3.0.3
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.6
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.3
  flutter_shapes:
  crypt:
  progress_dialog:
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/icons/account_icons/
    - assets/icons/departments/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/animations/
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a very old version of flutter_staggered_grid_view that does not support null-safety. Try editing your pubspec.yaml file to use a newer version .

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view/versions

For example:

```
 flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
```

You also need to update the flutter version specified in the pubspec.yaml file.

And then run flutter pub get.

Comment: yeah, but it's not the problem I try this solution

Comment: After updating the dependency and running "pub get" are you getting a different error message?

Comment: If you have a lot of outdated dependencies you may have to repeat this for other dependencies too. Running "pub outdated" can help you figure out which ones need upgrading.  And as you upgrade the dependencies, you may have to make code changes too. Take your time.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sdk value in pubspec and Upgrade the dependencies added in pubspec.yaml